# Look for content in csv files in a jar directory

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to use ZipFile to peek into a jar directory, and look for a certain content within the the csv files in that directory. So far I have:

```
def check_variable(jar_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(jar_path, 'r') as zipf:
        ret_reader = csv.reader(zipf)
        for row in ret_reader:
            if row[0] == 'Variable Label':
                return row[1]
    raise OutputError('Variable Label not found in file %s!' % ret_file_name)
```

This doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the traceback?

Comment: In addition to @yao99's comment, there is also https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print - when things do not work as expected, you may want to check what the variables contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zipfile.ZipFile(jar_path, 'r')` return a [`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) object. So you need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) the csv file in the zip file.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(jar_path, 'r') as zipf:
    with zipf.open(csv_path, 'r') as csvpf:
```